# assign a (numeric real) value to vertex in network graph

Tags: r, plot, social-networking, igraph, vertexdata

I wanted to assign or associate each node in the network plot with some real value (say some score) in `R`.
Which need to be updated in iterations.
Finally to plot the network graph with size of vertex according to its latest value (score).

Which property of a vertex I can use for this purpose and how?
If it's not possible in `igraph`, is there any other way to achieve this purpose in `R`?

I'm new to `R`. Anybody please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: create your own, e.g. if your graph is called `g` then `V(g)$Thokare <- 1:10` . Then `plot(g, vertex.size=V(g)$Thokare)`. Have you looked at the `igraph` documentation at all?

Comment: Why not to give a reproducible example with a sample of your data? what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

I create my gaph

```
graph2 <- read.table(text = '1 2 
1 3 
2 5 
3 4 
3 5 
4 5 
5 6 ')                    
par(mfrow =c(1,2)) 
graph2 <- graph.data.frame(graph2, 
           vertices = data.frame(symbols = 1:6,label   = 1:6),directed=FALSE)
plot(graph2,main='simple graph')
```

I change the weight property , here you can pput yor proper compting process

```
E(graph2)$weight <- seq(ecount(graph2))
graph.strength(graph2)
```

I modify property width, to visualize the weight effect

```
E(graph2)$width <-E(graph2)$weight                     
plot(graph2,main='weighted graph')
```

[image]